# How to filter and omit input data for d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am new to D3.JS and, as a beginner, I am not sure how to handle a demanding program that will read a lot of data from a csv file and then make customized output based on the input.  I am doing some test code in order to get the feel of the Here is the CSV file I am using:

```
location,age_group_id
USA,34
USA,34
USA,36
AFG,34
AFG,34
AFG,36
AFG,36
```

And the following code works fine to produce a simple bar graph based on this input:

```
<doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <title> Test </title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(error, data){

        var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
           .attr("width", 500)
           .attr("height", 500)

          canvas.selectAll("rect")
             .data(data)
             .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age_group_id * 10} )
               .attr("height", 48)
               .attr("y", function (d, i){return i * 50} )
               .attr("fill", "blue")
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But what if I wanted to filter this data and only show out put for "location" == USA?  I assume I would have to first read the data into a variable but I have yet to find documentation on how this is done.  I also assume I will have to first define the display in a  section and then load the data into this area.

Comment: Have a look at the filter function (see http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8dc93bce7e7200ab487d as example)

Comment: Thanks, Tim, that worked

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(error, data){
```

All your CSV is loaded, as an array of objects, in a variable named `data`.

Thus, you can create a new dataset based on `data`:

```
var dataUsa = data.filter(function(d){
    return d.location === "USA";
});
```

And use this dataset in the bars:

```
canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataUsa)
```

Comment: This will probably work too.  Thanks for your solution

Answer (score -1):

```
var country = "USA";


d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(error, data){


var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", 500)
   .attr("height", 500)

  canvas.selectAll("rect")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .filter(function(d) { return d.location == country })
       .append("rect")
       .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age_group_id * 10} )
       .attr("height", 48)
       .attr("y", function (d, i){return i * 50} )
       .attr("fill", "blue")
})
```